# Finality Flow not sending transaction to extraRecipients

Tags: corda

- Corda 2.0
- JDK 1.8.0_162

I'm trying to debug an inconsistent behaviour in FinalityFlow. Inconsistent as in different results in Mock and Real nodes.

**The Procedure on Real Nodes**

I'm trying to send a transaction to another node through one of the alternative FinalityFlow constructors:

```
constructor(transaction: SignedTransaction, extraParticipants: Set<Party>) : this(transaction, extraParticipants, tracker())
```

I communicate with my node through RPC. The procedure starts by retreiving the other node's Party by it's name, eg. `O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB`:

```
val extraRecipientParties = myExtraRecipientsStringList.map { rpcOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(CordaX500Name.build(X500Principal(it)))!! }
```

Then, rpcOps calls the flow responsible for creating a state:

```
val flow = rpcOps.startFlow(::CreateStateFlow, other, arguments, extraRecipientParties)
val result = flow.returnValue.getOrThrow()
val newState = result.tx.outRef<MyStateClass>(0)
```

**CreateStateFlow** is pretty standard:

```
@StartableByRPC
class CreateStateFlow(
        val s: String,
        val p: String,
        val o: String,
        val extraParticipants: List<Party>
) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {

    constructor(s: String, p: String, o: String): this(s, p, o, emptyList())


    @Suspendable
    override fun call() : SignedTransaction {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities.first()

        val newState = MyStateClass(ourIdentity, s, p, o, extraRecipients=extraParticipants)
        val command = Command(TripleContract.Create(), listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))
        val outputState = StateAndContract(newState, TripleContract.CONTRACT_REF)

        val utx = TransactionBuilder(notary=notary).withItems(
                command,
                outputState
        )

        val stx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(builder=utx, signingPubKeys=listOf(ourIdentity.owningKey))

        if (newState.extraRecipients.isEmpty()) {
            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx))
        }

        return subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx, newState.extraRecipients.toSet() ))

    }
}
```

What I expect is that now, on any node owned by parties in the extraRecipients variable, I should be able to find `newState` by querying the vault.
Indeed, this is true when I test it on Mock nodes, but not when rpc calls

```
rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<MyStateClass>().states --> returns an empty list
```

**Test on Mock Nodes**

```
@Test
fun `FinalityFlow used to federate a transaction`(){
    val partyAString = node1.info.legalIdentities.first().name.toString()
    val aStringX500Name = CordaX500Name.build(X500Principal(partyAString))
    val node2FindPartyA = node2.rpcOps.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(aStringX500Name)!!
    assert(node1.info.legalIdentities.contains(node2FindPartyA))

    val executingFlow = node2.start(CreateStateFlow("fo", "boo", "bar", listOf(node2FindPartyA)))
    val flowResult = executingFlow.getOrThrow()
    val stateInNode2 = flowResult.tx.outRef<MyStateClass>(0)
    val stateInNode1 = node1.database.transaction {
        node1.services.loadState(stateInNode2.ref)
    }
    assert(stateInNode1.data == stateInNode2.state.data)
```

Edit:
**MyStateClass.kt**

```
data class MyStateClass(
        val owner: Party,
        val s: String,
        val p: String,
        val o: String,
        val extraRecipients: List<Party>,
        val lastEditor: AbstractParty = owner,
        override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(owner),
        override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()
) : LinearState, QueryableState {

    object MyStateSchemaV1 : MappedSchema(MyStateClass::class.java, 1, listOf(MyStateEntity::class.java)) {
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "my-state")
        class MyStateEntity(state: MyStateClass) : PersistentState() {

            @Column @Lob
            var owner: ByteArray = state.owner.owningKey.encoded

            @Column
            var s: String = state.s

            @Column
            var p: String = state.p

            @Column
            var o: String = state.o

            @Column @ElementCollection
            var extra_recipients: Set<ByteArray> = state.extraRecipients.map { it.owningKey.encoded }.toSet()

            @Column @ElementCollection
            var participants: Set<ByteArray> = state.participants.map { it.owningKey.encoded }.toSet()

            @Column @Lob
            var last_editor: ByteArray = state.owner.owningKey.encoded

            @Column
            var linear_id: String = state.linearId.id.toString()
        }

    }

    override fun supportedSchemas(): Iterable<MappedSchema> = listOf(MyStateSchemaV1)
    override fun generateMappedObject(schema: MappedSchema): PersistentState = MyStateSchemaV1.MyStateEntity(this)

}
```

Comment: Mind posting your state class code?

Comment: Here you go @Adrian it implements Queryable and Linear State

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you introduced a new variable `val extraRecipients: List<Party>`, your participants is only on the owner, `override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(owner)` Therefore only the owner party should have the state in the vault.

The extraRecipients in FinalityFlow do not store the states in the vault (states storage), but they store the copy of the notarised transaction in the transaction storage.

The definition of `loadState` function is `Given a [StateRef] loads the referenced transaction and looks up the specified output [ContractState].` Because node 1 was added as a extra recipient of the transaction  in finality flow (think of it as the cc-ed recipient of an email), when asked to `loadState`, it was able to deduce the state from the transaction storage since it consists of inputs, commands, outputs, etc. So here you've proven that the transaction was sent to the other parties during `FinalityFlow`.

While on the `rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<MyStateClass>().states`, it was actually querying states from the node states vault - not transaction storage, therefore returned an empty list.

If you want the extraRecipients to store the state, you'll need to add them in the `participants` field of the state or use `observable-states` concept [here](https://github.com/roger3cev/observable-states/blob/master/cordapp/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/demos/crowdFunding/flows/RecordTransactionAsObserver.kt).

Comment: I thought all states ended up in the vault the transaction storage referenced those. I know what to do from here. Thanks for the answer, it was really helpful and well worded!